# Getting a control name/Displaying tooltip text

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms, user-interface

I am developing a form with multiple options that simulates a signup form, and I want to display some tips and descriptions in a `RichTextBox` located by the options when the user's mouse hover by it's `GroupBoxes`.

Since I am fairly new to programming, I don't know if getting all the controls names one by one is the optimal, so I want to grab the controls' names inside of the `tabControl` control that I am using to organize everything.

```
private void TabControl1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        string name = c.Name;
        TooltipText(name);
    }
}
```

And I also have a method where I will write the text that will be displayed in the `RichTextBox`.

```
private string TooltipText(string name)
{
    if(name == "Name:")
    {
        return "blabla";
    }
    else
    {
        return "none";
    }
}
```

I've tried a generic method to show a message box if the control was detected and, as I suspected, nothing showed up:

```
private void TooltipText(string name)
{
    if(name == "LBL_Name")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hey");
        return;
    }
}
```

How can I properly detect the `Groupboxes` or other types of Controls inside of the `TabControl` control, and also display the text in the box beside it?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to create your own Tool Tips. The .net WinForms provides a ToolTip class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip?view=netframework-4.8

I added 2 radio buttons to a group box in design view.
Try it and see.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
        tip.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
        tip.InitialDelay = 1000;
        tip.ReshowDelay = 500;
        tip.SetToolTip(radioButton1, "Choose to Add Onions");
        tip.SetToolTip(radioButton2, "Choose to Add Pickles");
    }
```